# Difference between tag and class in Stanford NER

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp

I'm not sure what the difference between tag and class is?

[NERFeatureFactory](http://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/ie/NERFeatureFactory.html) mentions:

```
t - tag
c - class
```

The NER [FAQ](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/crf-faq.shtml) seems to use the two terms interchangeably as well?

For example what does the following feature do?

```
t,c   useTags
```

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Gabor said, tag is part of speech tag.

However, for c (or class): the features are defined over each class (so, John-NAME and John-PLACE are two different features).

useTags feature would be something like NNP-NAME, RB-PLACE, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

My informed guess is that actually neither tag nor class refer to the NER tag, but rather "tag" is the part of speech tag, and class is the word class (e.g., brown cluster).